# MediaHTTPConnectionEx com.lge.media.MediaHTTPConnectionEx 442 seekTo exception toString: java.io.IOException

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have a `VideoView` in my app that streams videos from server. In some cases player raises an exception that posted below

> com.lge.media.MediaHTTPConnectionEx 442 seekTo exception toString: java.io.IOException

Can anyone help me ?

90% of videos play well but some of them doesn't play.

My logcat is here for more information

```
09-04 16:04:20.900 7041-7052/com.amnmoj.toop360 D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response code] STATUS CODE:403
09-04 16:04:20.901 7041-7052/com.amnmoj.toop360 D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [ResponseMessage]:Forbidden
09-04 16:04:20.901 7041-7052/com.amnmoj.toop360 E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: MediaHTTPConnectionEx com.lge.media.MediaHTTPConnectionEx 442 seekTo exception toString: java.io.IOException
09-04 16:04:23.906 7041-7053/com.amnmoj.toop360 E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: connect
09-04 16:04:23.906 7041-7053/com.amnmoj.toop360 E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: disconnecting
09-04 16:04:23.906 7041-7053/com.amnmoj.toop360 E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: disconnected
09-04 16:04:23.907 7041-7053/com.amnmoj.toop360 D/MediaHTTPConnection: filterOutInternalHeaders: key=User-Agent, val= LG-H818P/V20e Player/LG Player 1.0 for Android 6.0 (stagefright alternative)
09-04 16:04:23.907 7041-7359/com.amnmoj.toop360 E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [seekToEx] offset:0/mCurrentOffset:-1
09-04 16:04:23.908 7041-7359/com.amnmoj.toop360 D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: proxy null port 0
09-04 16:04:25.211 7041-7359/com.amnmoj.toop360 D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response code] STATUS CODE:403
09-04 16:04:25.212 7041-7359/com.amnmoj.toop360 D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [ResponseMessage]:Forbidden
09-04 16:04:25.212 7041-7359/com.amnmoj.toop360 E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: MediaHTTPConnectionEx com.lge.media.MediaHTTPConnectionEx 442 seekTo exception toString: java.io.IOException
09-04 16:04:25.217 7041-7059/com.amnmoj.toop360 V/MediaPlayer[Native]: message received msg=200, ext1=702, ext2=0
09-04 16:04:25.217 7041-7059/com.amnmoj.toop360 W/MediaPlayer[Native]: info/warning (702, 0)
09-04 16:04:25.217 7041-7059/com.amnmoj.toop360 V/MediaPlayer[Native]: callback application
09-04 16:04:25.217 7041-7059/com.amnmoj.toop360 V/MediaPlayer[Native]: back from callback
09-04 16:04:25.249 7041-7041/com.amnmoj.toop360 V/MediaPlayer[Native]: isPlaying: 0
```

Comment: My device is LG G4

Comment: Can't say I know anything about videoview, but 403 forbidden in the log implies you simply don't have access to whatever file you are attempting to stream?

Comment: @Thernys when do I can't access to media in server like this? both client-side and server-side are working properly in other cases

Comment: It is impossible to say based on the information in your question. Perhaps some files on the server are not accessible by the user that your server process runs as (wrong file owner or access permissions).

Comment: @Thernys thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved!

In our company we use 3 internet provider with one modem which has set to connect with best provider.
when the best changes, the server block my connection because of some security issues...
So when I want to use my app I have to make modem don't change connection.
There is another way to solve this problem, we can change server-side codes to not block these situations!

Hope this help you :)